# LINQ anonymous casting exception

Tags: c#, linq

New to LINQ ... thought I would give it a "simple" try and get my feet wet (so to say)... I went to MS's site (101 easy linq's or something like that that) pulled an example and tried to modify it.

Here are the classes I am working with:

```
public class RPt
{
    public RPt(int n, LatLon ll, int pt){Road = n;LL = ll;Pt = pt;}
    public int Road;
    public LatLon LL;
    public int Pt;
}

public class dRpt : RPt
{
    public dRpt(double d, RPt r) : base(r.Road, r.LL, r.Pt){D = d;}
    public double D;
};

public class LatLon
{
    public LatLon() { Latitude = 0.0; Longitude = 0.0; }
    public LatLon(double lat, double lon){ Latitude = lat; Longitude = lon; }
    public double Latitude { get; set; }
    public double Longitude { get; set; }
}

public class RoadList : List<RPt>
{
    public RoadList(){}

    public void FillIt()
    {
        RPt ll = null;
        ll = new RPt(1, new LatLon(37.252450, -122.058259), 10); this.Add(ll);
        ll = new RPt(1, new LatLon(37.248640, -122.068356), 20); this.Add(ll);
        ll = new RPt(1, new LatLon(37.254100, -122.089025), 30); this.Add(ll);
        ll = new RPt(1, new LatLon(37.261881, -122.102711), 40); this.Add(ll);
        ll = new RPt(1, new LatLon(37.260418, -122.112793), 50); this.Add(ll);
        ll = new RPt(1, new LatLon(37.256413, -122.116153), 60); this.Add(ll);
        ll = new RPt(1, new LatLon(37.258525, -122.121971), 70); this.Add(ll);
        ll = new RPt(2, new LatLon(37.258525, -122.121971), 10); this.Add(ll);
        ll = new RPt(2, new LatLon(37.259727, -122.124134), 20); this.Add(ll);
        ll = new RPt(2, new LatLon(37.259971, -122.129823), 30); this.Add(ll);
        ll = new RPt(2, new LatLon(37.267248, -122.138307), 40); this.Add(ll);
        ll = new RPt(2, new LatLon(37.285609, -122.152232), 50); this.Add(ll);
        ll = new RPt(2, new LatLon(37.291702, -122.156238), 60); this.Add(ll);
        ll = new RPt(2, new LatLon(37.293491, -122.161288), 70); this.Add(ll);
    }
}
```

I am trying to filter a RoadList using a LINQ statement (like a sql join) and then have that filtered result set cast back to my RoadList instead of an anonymous 'var'.

Here is the setup function:

```
    RoadList hwy;
    private void TestLinq()
    {
        hwy = new RoadList();
        hwy.FillIt();

        List<int> list = new List<int>() { 10 };

        try
        {
            RoadList filtered = LinqFilter(list, hwy);
        }
        catch (Exception ex)
        {
            Debug.WriteLine(ex.ToString());
        }

    }
```

Here is the LINQ code: ( and the problem area )

```
    private RoadList LinqFilter(List<int> list, RoadList input)
    {
        RoadList retval = null;

        // this does what I want it to do...
        // returns only the list of RPt objects that match the ints
        // in the incoming list
        var q2 =
        from c in input
        join p in list on c.Pt equals p
        select new { RPt = c };

        retval = (RoadList)q2;  // <<== This is where I get the exception !

        foreach (RPt rpt in retval)
        {
            Debug.WriteLine(rpt.ToString());
        }

        return retval;
    }
```

Here is the exception I am getting:

```
Unable to cast object of type '<JoinIterator>d__61`4[deleteMe_Test.RPt,System.Int32,System.Int32,<>f__AnonymousType1`1[deleteMe_Test.RPt]]' to type 'deleteMe_Test.RoadList'."
```

Help... need to get back to my class object so I can return it to another function !

Thank you.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You're trying to use `q2` as if it were a `RoadList`, but it's not. It's an `IEnumerable<'a>` where `'a` is an [anonymous type](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/bb397696.aspx) with a `public RPt RPt` property. Quite different things...

The anonymous type is unnecessary, so first change to:

```
var q2 =
from c in input
join p in list on c.Pt equals p
select c;
```

to get an `IEnumerable<RPt>`. Now you need to create a `RoadList` containing this. I'd suggest you create a new constructor in `RoadList` that takes an `IEnumerable<RPt>` and passes it down to the `List<T>(IEnumerable<T>)` constructor

```
public RoadList(IEnumerable<RPt> items) : base(items) {}
```

Then you can have:

```
retval = new RoadList(q2);
```

And everything else should work as expected.